# Javascript SharePoint Date Column format

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I am using this piece of code to check whether an item has gone beyond its Expiry date.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 (function () {
var statusFieldCtx = {};

statusFieldCtx.Templates = {};
statusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
    "Expiry_x0020_Date": {"View": StatusIconViewTemplate}
};

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldCtx);
})();

function StatusIconViewTemplate(ctx) {
var _dueDate = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.Expiry_x0020_Date);


var now = new Date();
var nowPlus = new Date();
nowPlus.setDate(now.getDate()+7);
if (_dueDate == 'undefined' || !_dueDate) {
    return '';
}
else if (_dueDate < now) 
{
    return "<span><font style='color:red'>" + _dueDate.toLocaleDateString()  + "&nbsp;<img src='/PublishingImages/red.jpg'/></font></span>";
}
else if (_dueDate >= now && _dueDate <= nowPlus) 
{
    return "<span><font style='color:black'>" + _dueDate.toLocaleDateString() + "&nbsp;<img src='/PublishingImages/yellow.jpg'/></font></span>";
}
else if (_dueDate > now) 
{
    return "<span><font style='color:black'>" + _dueDate.toLocaleDateString() + "<img src='/PublishingImages/green.jpg'/></font></span>";
}
}</script>
```

The problem I am facing is that, the _dueDate is coming in the US date format 'Thu Aug 6 00:00:00 UTC +0100 2015' for a date 08/06/2015

Is there anything I am doing wrong, how do I correct this to show up in the UK format?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string to `Date` javascript object and compose the format you want

```
var d = new Date('Thu Aug 6 00:00:00 UTC +0100 2015');
var ukDate = (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
```

You can use all functions of Date object; for a complete list you can see the [Developer Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)